# std function with object member callback

Tags: c++, event-handling

I have a class that fires events, and I want to handle those event in another class. The following code shows what I am trying to achieve:

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class StatusReport {
public:
    int value;
};

class Sender {
public:
    function<void(StatusReport *report)> ReportEvent;

    void test() {
        StatusReport *r = new StatusReport();
        ReportEvent(r);
    }
};


class Receiver {
public:
    Receiver() {
        Sender s = Sender();
        s.ReportEvent = std::bind(&Receiver::StatusReportEvent, this);
    }

    void StatusReportEvent(StatusReport *report) {
    }
};

int main() {
    Receiver r();
    return 0;
}
```

This generates an error when I try to bind the event to a method inside my receiver object. The error is

```
no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Receiver::*)(StatusReport*)>(Receiver*)>) (StatusReport*)’
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function receives argument of type `StatusReport` bind should be called like

```
s.ReportEvent = std::bind
(
   &Receiver::StatusReportEvent, this, std::placeholders::_1
);
```

`std::placeholders::_1` is a [placeholder](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) for argument.

Comment: thank you for the reply. it solves the issue, even though I have also found that using lambdas also fixes it: function<void(StatusReport*)> f = [=](StatusReport *r) {
  this->StatusReportEvent(r);
 };